# R: Generate a list that contains a varying number of elements from the global environment with a certain prefix

Tags: r, list

I am trying to generate a list, that contains elements with a prefix ('nu_') from the global environment (integers in this case, named 'nu_1', 'nu_2', ...).

However, the number of these elements can change, so I need a way to get all relevant elements dynamically based on their prefix and combine them into a list.

Some background information:

The goal is to let the user input a number of strings (company names) that refer to column names in a dataframe. I want the sums of all of these columns in this list. I get these sums using the following for-loop and assign them to integers with the prefix "nu_".

```
strings <- list("Amazon", "Google", "Facebook")

for (i in 1:length(strings)){
    assign(paste0("nu_",i), sum(data[ grep(paste0("company_",strings[i]),colnames(data)) ]) )
}
```

Maybe there is a better way to achieve my goal overall.
Any help for my problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Consider building a list of sums with *apply* family (`l/s/vapply`) to maintain one object as opposed to many separate objects depending on user input. And if using a character vector instead of list with `sapply`, the output is a named list. Consider also pasting *company_* prefix from vector:

```
# CHARACTER VECTOR OF THREE ITEMS
strings <- paste0("company_", c("Amazon", "Google", "Facebook"))
# EQUIVALENTLY:
strings <- paste0("company_", unlist(list("Amazon", "Google", "Facebook")))

sum_list <- sapply(strings, function(i) sum(data[,grep(i,colnames(data))]),
                   simplify=FALSE)

sum_list$company_Amazon
sum_list$company_Google
sum_list$company_Facebook
```

And if neededing to rename for *nu* prefix, use `setNames` off the sequence of *strings*:

```
sum_list <- setNames(sum_list, paste0("nu", seq_along(strings)))

sum_list$nu1
sum_list$nu2
sum_list$nu3
```